# How can I trigger a server-side event from a client-side event?

Tags: asp.net, modalpopup

#### Short version

All I need is that, in a `ModalPopUp`, when the `DoubleClick` event of a `ListItem` fires, the click event of my OK button should be executed.

#### Detail

I have a `ModalPopUpExtender`, which hosts a user control. The user control has an `OK` and a `Cancel` button. Along with that, it has a dynamic `ListBox` added to it. So far, I've considered the following possible solutions:

1. Use Ajax.Net. But, I cannot afford to have a WebMethod.
2. Use a `ClientScriptCallBack`. This will need a lot of JavaScript, since I have made almost every control dynamic.

Is there any other way apart from using an `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this way using __doPostback

[calling a VB.net function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905387/calling-a-vb-net-function-from-javascript/905404#905404)